# Watch videos from fpv camera without goggles

Tags: fpv-cameras, camera

I have this vtx VTX Eachine TX805 (25mw - 800mw) analogic + antena foxeer
with a standard CM1200 analogique 25x25 camera.
But I don't have gogles, and I would like to capture videos, pictures and to have the real-time display on my ground station (my laptop with mission planner). is it possible, and if yes how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an FPV receiver; they output a TV signal. You can just plug that into a TV to watch the signal, but you won't be able to record it. (I guess you could use an old VHS recorder!)

To watch or record it on a lap top, you'd need a TV capture device that converts the analog signal to digital.

Most people don't do this, as it's more expensive than a cheap set of goggles, adds some lag, and the laptop screen can be hard to see when the sun is shining on it.